# FastAPI - Best practices for writing REST APIs with multiple conditions

Tags: python, rest, design-patterns, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Let's say I have two entities, `Users` and `Councils`, and a M2M association table `UserCouncils`. `Users` can be added/removed from `Councils` and only admins can do that (defined in a `role` attribute in the `UserCouncil` relation).
Now, when creating endpoints for `/councils/{council_id}/remove`, I am faced with the issue of checking multiple constraints before the operation, such as the following:

```py
@router.delete("/{council_id}/remove", response_model=responses.CouncilDetail)
def remove_user_from_council(
    council_id: int | UUID = Path(...),
    *,
    user_in: schemas.CouncilUser,
    db: Session = Depends(get_db),
    current_user: Users = Depends(get_current_user),
    council: Councils = Depends(council_id_dep),
) -> dict[str, Any]:
    """

    DELETE /councils/:id/remove (auth)

    remove user with `user_in` from council
    current user must be ADMIN of council
    """

    # check if input user exists
    if not Users.get(db=db, id=user_in.user_id):
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail="User not found"
        )

    if not UserCouncil.get(db=db, user_id=user_in.user_id, council_id=council.id):
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail="Cannot delete user who is not part of council",
        )

    # check if current user exists in council
    if not (
        relation := UserCouncil.get(
            db=db, user_id=current_user.id, council_id=council.id
        )
    ):
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN,
            detail="Current user not part of council",
        )

    # check if current user is Admin
    if relation.role != Roles.ADMIN:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN, detail="Unauthorized"
        )

    elif current_user.id == user_in.user_id:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail="Admin cannot delete themselves",
        )

    else:
        updated_users = council.remove_member(db=db, user_id=user_in.user_id)
        result = {"council": council, "users": updated_users}
        return result
```

These checks are pretty self-explanatory. However, this adds a lot of code in the endpoint definition. Should the endpoint definitions be generally minimalistic? I could wrap all these checks inside the `Councils` crud method (i.e., `council.remove_member()`), but that would mean adding `HTTPException`s inside crud classes, which I don't want to do.

What are the general best practices for solving situations like these, and where can I read more about this? Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have to check that user exists _after_ using a dependency that fetches the current user? That dependency should verify that the user exists and is a valid user; the same can be said for the code fetching the council; make it depend on both the user and the council id, and resolve that in your depenendency. You can also make that dependency a `council_with_current_user_as_admin`, so that it's all hidden away behind layers of dependencies. Your view becomes very effective and succinct, and your dependencies can easily be reused to compose different needs.

Comment: The check for user exists is for the input user `user_in`. `current_user` only parses the header to fetch the currently logged in user. But you're right. A relationship dependency would clear the clutter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I will tell you how I would go about doing it with your example.

Generally I like to keep my endpoints quite minimal. What you what to employ is a common pattern used in building APIs and that is to bundle your business logic into a service class. This service class allows you to reuse logic. Say you want to remove a council member from a queue or cron job. This brings up the next issue you highlighted and that is about having HTTP specific exceptions in your service class which may not be used in an HTTP context. Fortunately this is not a difficult one to solve, you can just define your own exceptions and ask the API framework to catch them only to re-raise the desired HTTP exception.

Define a custom exception:

```py
class UnauthorizedException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message: str):
        super().__init__(message)
        self.message = message


class InvalidActionException(Exception):
    ...


class NotFoundException(Exception):
    ...
```

In Fast API you can catch specific exceptions your application throws

```py
@app.exception_handler(UnauthorizedException)
async def unauthorized_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: UnauthorizedException):
    return JSONResponse(
            status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN,
            content={"message": exc.message},
    )

@app.exception_handler(InvalidActionException)
async def unauthorized_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: InvalidActionException):
    ...
```

Wrap up your business logic into a service class with sensible methods and raise the exceptions you have defined for your service

```py
class CouncilService:
    def __init__(self, db: Session):
        self.db = db

    def ensure_admin_council_member(self, user_id: int, council_id: int):
        # check if current user exists in council
        if not (
                relation := UserCouncil.get(
                        db=self.db, user_id=user_id, council_id=council_id
                )
        ):
            raise UnauthorizedException("Current user not part of council")

        # check if current user is Admin
        if relation.role != Roles.ADMIN:
            raise UnauthorizedException("Unauthorized")

    def remove_council_member(self, user_in: schemas.CouncilUser, council: Councils):
        # check if input user exists
        if not Users.get(db=self.db, id=user_in.user_id):
            raise NotFoundException("User not found")

        if not UserCouncil.get(db=self.db, user_id=user_in.user_id, council_id=council.id):
            raise InvalidActionException("Cannot delete user who is not part of council")

        if current_user.id == user_in.user_id:
            raise InvalidActionException("Admin cannot delete themselves")

        updated_users = council.remove_member(db=self.db, user_id=user_in.user_id)
        result = {"council": council, "users": updated_users}
        return result
```

and then finally your endpoint definition is quite lean

EDIT: removed the `/remove` verb from the path, as pointed out in the comments, the verb is already specified. Ideally your path should contain Nouns referring to the resource.

```py
@router.delete("/{council_id}", response_model=responses.CouncilDetail)
def remove_user_from_council(
    council_id: int | UUID = Path(...),
    *,
    user_in: schemas.CouncilUser,
    current_user: Users = Depends(get_current_user),
    council: Councils = Depends(council_id_dep),
    council_service: CouncilService = Depends(get_council_service),
) -> responses.CouncilDetail:
    """

    DELETE /councils/:id (auth)

    remove user with `user_in` from council
    current user must be ADMIN of council
    """
    council_service.ensure_admin_council_member(current_user.id, council_id)
    return council_service.remove_council_member(user_in, council)
```

Comment: In general, adding verbs like "remove" from a HTTP DELETE method should be avoided. You already knowingly are calling "delete this id" from the API path and HTTP method itself. There is no need for the verb

Comment: @OneCricketeer very good point, I have edited the answer